# Is it possible to evaluate object as boolean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Test {
    is_valid = true;

    constructor (value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    is_less_than (number) {
        if (this.value >= number)
            this.is_valid = false;
        return this;
    }

    is_greater_than (number) {
        if (this.value <= number)
            this.is_valid = false;
        return this;
    }
}

const is_valid = new Test(5).is_less_than(10),
      is_valid2 = new Test(5).is_less_than(10).is_greater_than(7);

if (is_valid)
    console.log(1); // 1
else
    console.log(0);

if (is_valid2)
    console.log(1);
else
    console.log(0); // 0
```

I want to implement that pattern using any solutions. I have tried various tests with valueOf(), toString(), setting context, Boolean... I'm not sure whether It's possible. If you know about it, let me know please.

---

The reason I didn't use *is_valid* property is to avoid mistakes that only use a object that the result of method channing without using *is_valid*.

Below pattern is also possible, but isn't satisfactory.

```
new Test().is_less_than(10).is_valid(5)
```

Comment: Just check the `valid` property of `Test`? I.e. instead of `if (is_valid)`, check `if (is_valid.is_valid)`.

Comment: Or, rather, instead of `const is_valid = new Test(5).is_less_than(10),`, do `const is_valid = new Test(5).is_less_than(10).is_valid`.

Comment: In programming languages, `less_than` means `<`, and `less_equal` means `<=`. So your naming can be confusing others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `is_valid` and `is_valid2` are instances of the class `Test`, so they are objects.
To check the `Test.is_valid` value, you should use something like this:

```
const is_valid = new Test(5).is_less_than(10).is_valid, 
      is_valid2 = new Test(5).is_less_than(10).is_greater_than(7).is_valid;
```